# Stubbing nested component with its own nested components in angular test

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component (Parent), which has a custom nested component (ChildOne) which has its own custom nested component (ChildTwo). I want to unit test Parent, so I have created stubs for the children. However, stubbing a component seems to cause it not to have any children, so ChildTwo is missing which is needed for my test. Is there a way I can stub a component, while keeping it's children?

HTML:

```html
<app-child-one>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <app-child-two (click)="onClick($event)">
    </app-child-two>
  </div>
</app-child-one>
```

Typescript:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {

    onClick(event: Event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Spec:

```js
@Component({ selector: 'app-child-one', template: '' })
export class ChildOneStubComponent {

}

@Component({ selector: 'app-child-two', template: '' })
export class ChildTwoStubComponent {

}

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ParentComponent, ChildOneStubComponent, ChildTwoStubComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('calls onClick when child two is clicked', () => {
    const childTwo = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-child-two'));
    childTwo.triggerEventHandler('click', null); // <-- this fails, child two is null

    expect(...);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this myself, I just had to add `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the stub template and now it seems to work.

```js
@Component({ selector: 'app-child-one', template: '<ng-content></ng-content>' })
export class ChildOneStubComponent {

}
```